# How should I go about debugging a SIGFPE in a large, unfamiliar software project?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, kde-plasma

I'm trying to get to the bottom of a bug in KDE 5.6. The locker screen breaks no matter how I lock it. Here's the relevant code: https://github.com/KDE/kscreenlocker/blob/master/abstractlocker.cpp#L51

When I run `/usr/lib/kscreenlocker_greet --testing`, I get an output of:

```
KCrash: Application 'kscreenlocker_greet' crashing...
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I'm trying to run it with `gdb` to try and pin the exact location of the bug, but I'm not sure where to set the breakpoints in order to isolate the bug. Should I be looking for calls to `KCrash`? Or perhaps a `raise()` call? Can I get `gdb` to print off the relevant line of code that causes SIGFPE?

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Run program under gdb and when it crashes, enter "bt".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I'm not sure where to set the breakpoints in order to isolate the bug

You shouldn't need to set any breakpoints at all: when a process running under GDB encounters a fatal signal (such as `SIGFPE`), the OS notices that the process is being traced by the debugger, and notifies the debugger (instead of terminating the process). That in turn causes GDB to stop, and prompt you for additional commands. It is *at that time* that you can look around and understand what caused the crash.

Example:

```
cat -n t.c
     1  #include <fenv.h>
     2
     3  int foo(double d) {
     4    return 1/d;
     5  }
     6
     7  int main()
     8  {
     9    feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO);
    10    return foo(0);
    11  }

gcc -g t.c -lm
./a.out
Floating point exception

gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x000000000040060e in foo (d=0) at t.c:4
4     return 1/d;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040060e in foo (d=0) at t.c:4
#1  0x0000000000400635 in main () at t.c:10
(gdb) q
```

Here, as you can see, GDB stops when `SIGFPE` is delivered, and allows you to look around and understand the crash.

In your case, you would want to first install debuginfo symbols for KDE, and then run

```
gdb --args /usr/lib/kscreenlocker_greet --testing
(gdb) run
```